# append li in ul which contain multiple spaces

Tags: jquery

I want to append `<li>` in `<ul>` using jQuery. I've done it successfully with the following line:

```
var ChosedItem = $("#chosedItem");
ChosedItem.append('<li id=' + $(this).attr('id') + ' limit=' + $(this).attr('limit') + ' ><span>' + $(this).children(0) + '</span></li>');
```

in this, `#chosedItem` is the div id where the `<ul>` exists

But the problem in my case is if my `<li>` items contain spaces then it is not added after `[0]th` position of children because I am using `chlidren(0)`. What can I use in place of `children(0)` to add `<li>` items that contain multiple spaces?

Comment: In future, please spend more time writing or formatting your post. Formatting help can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#chosedItem').children().filter(function(){    

  if($(this).text().split(' ').length > 2) //Elements with two or more space will be returned
     return $(this);

}).append('<li id=' + $(this).attr('id') + ' limit=' + $(this).attr('limit') + ' ><span>' + $(this).children(0) + '</span></li>');
```

Comment: thanks...
$(this).text() helps me to solve my problem....it append li that contain multiple spaces.